# Running Text as Breaking News animation in React-Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm new in React-Native Animation.

I want to create **Running Text** like **Running Text** in **Breaking News**.

> Appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether you want to create the animation on your own or just use existing components. If you just need the animation, try importing components like [react-native-marquee](https://github.com/kyo504/react-native-marquee) or [react-native-marquee-label](https://github.com/remobile/react-native-marquee-label).

If you want to understand how it's done and want to implement it yourself, just have a look at the source codes of those projects, e. g. [this one](https://github.com/kyo504/react-native-marquee/blob/master/index.js).